# Post to page wall as fan(user) Android Facebook Open Graph Api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm a newbie to Facebook Android Sdk and using the Open Graph Api.
What i want to do is very specific.
I'm developing an android app that fetches my facebook page feed (which includes page posts and fan's posts) (in json format) and displays the content in my app.
So I want to give the opportunity to my android app user , after logging into facebook , to be able to send his message and photo on facebook page wall  (as fan/user of course), so it will be in my facebook feed and displayed finally into my application.
I cloned some projects found on github , trying to gain some practical knowledge on facebook android sdk , but the only thing i achieved , after logging in my facebook personal account inside my application , was either share link content on my wall (postTowall function) or upload image on my personal wall.

The only thing that i found after hours of searching , was about to publish to a page that you own as the page.I don't want that.
I just want to interact in that way with my app fans.

**if direct posting on facebook page fan's wall can not be achieved , then the other solution that i have thought to upload and display content in my app is using : ""/{page-id}/tagged"" which shows all public posts in which the page has been tagged.
So , if a user of my android application would like to upload content that will be displayed into the application , should log in facebook and mention my facebook page name with his posts(message,photo)

Comment: Publishing to a page as a user works the same way as publishing as the page does - only that you do not use the page access token, but the user access token.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your reply!!Is there any link given explaining step-by-step how to do this in android application?(Because everything I found is 3-4 years ago and furthermore i'm still beginner on writing alone all these functions).

Comment: The official docs for the Android SDK in the FB dev section have some examples how basic API requests work.